# how to make a react-native full screen modal in ios

Tags: ios, react-native, modalviewcontroller

I am trying to use react native to achieve the modal effect of iOS, and also refer to [react-native-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal/),now I want a full-screen effect，like `presentationStyle = .full screen` in ios,so how can i get it? My react-native version seems like 0.66.0

Here is my code:

App.js:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import Screen_A from "./src/Screen_A";
import Screen_B from "./src/Screen_B";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Screen_A" component={Screen_A} />
        <Stack.Group screenOptions={{presentation: 'modal'}}>
          <Stack.Screen name="Screen_B" component={Screen_B} />
        </Stack.Group>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Screen A:

```
export default Screen_A = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 40 }}>Screen A</Text>
            <Pressable
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Screen_B')}
                style={({ pressed }) => [
                    {
                        backgroundColor: pressed
                            ? 'rgb(210, 230, 255)'
                            : 'white'
                    },
                    styles.wrapperCustom,
                    { marginTop: 20 }
                ]}>
                {({ pressed }) => (
                    <Text style={[styles.text, { fontSize: 40 }]}>
                        {pressed ? 'Pressed!' : 'Go to Screen B'}
                    </Text>
                )}
            </Pressable>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Screen B：

```
export default Screen_B = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 40}}>Screen B</Text>
            <Pressable
                style={{ marginTop: 20, backgroundColor: 'red' }}
                onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
            >
                <Text>Go back Screen A</Text>
            </Pressable>
        </View>
    )
}
```

result:
[image]

---

**As the picture shows, Screen B is not displayed in full screen（There is about 10% spacing at the top）, so how can I implement it? Thanks!**

Comment: React navigation provide a sample -> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal/

Comment: @MichaelBahl i tried the sample code,but still not full screen.

Comment: So you don't want a modal, you want just a fullscreen window?

Comment: Actually,i just want a full screen modal,but i dont know how to make it in 6.x version. I tried it can be easily achieved under the 5.x version。So I downgraded the version to 5.x。[see here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-5.x/#modemodal-is-removed-in-favor-of-presentation-modal)

Comment: @Ben on v6 for least iOS I see forVerticalIOS works for me https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#cardstyleinterpolators

Answer (score 0):

I modified an fullscreen modal [sample](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal) to fir your needs

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <RootStack.Navigator>
    <RootStack.Group>
      <RootStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <RootStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
    </RootStack.Group>
    <RootStack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'card', headerMode:"none" }}>
      <RootStack.Screen name="MyModal" component={ModalScreen} />
    </RootStack.Group>
  </RootStack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: > The presentation option for stack navigator can be either card
> (default) or modal.

Presentation props is useless here